# SuppressionFilter is not working

Tags: checkstyle

SuppressionFilter is not ignoring the files which are given in suppressions.xml

In `checkstyle.xml`,

```
<module name="Checker">
    <module name="SuppressionFilter">
      <property name="file" value="/home/svn/testrepo/scripts/suppressions.xml"/>
    </module>
    <module name="TreeWalker">
....
</module>
```

In `suppressions.xml` (which is in /home/svn/testrepo/scripts),

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">
<suppressions>
    <suppress checks="."
              files="Constants.java" />
</suppressions>
```

Also, tried with the below one:

```
<suppressions>
    <suppress files="Constants\.java" checks="[a-zA-Z0-9]*"/>
</suppressions>
```

Also, tried with:

```
<suppressions>
    <suppress checks=".*"
              files="Constants.java" />
</suppressions>
```

None of the options are working. Can anybody have answers on this? Please help me out.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you configure the filter using:

```
    <module name="SuppressionFilter">
      <property name="file" value="suppressions.xml"/>
    </module>
```

Then an example content of *suppressions.xml* could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
    "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.1//EN"
    "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_1.dtd">
<suppressions>
    <suppress checks="."  files="[\\/]SoapAdapter\.java$"/>
</suppressions>
```

This will then suppress **all** checks for the files named *SoapAdapter.java*. Note that `[\\/]` is just a regular expression to handle file names under Unix (which use `/`) and Windows (which use `\`).

Also recommend reading the Checkstyle documenation on the subject at http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html.

Answer (score 2):

just add `${config_loc}` in front of value as described in the [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html#sec:checkstyle_configuration)

```
<module name="SuppressionFilter">
    <property name="file" value="${config_loc}/suppressions.xml"/>
</module>
```